# Using Google Apps Standard - Emails being marked as spam

Tags: email, email-spam

I signed up with Google apps standard edition for one of my domain names say example.com. I setup the emails like contact@example.com - and using the Google Email client and loggin as user contact - if I send emails to users - they arrive in their inbox.

But when I send it through my php script running on my hosting account where I have registered the domain example.com - using the same email address contact@example.com - it ends up in the Spam folder - I've noticed this in both yahoo and gmail accounts

Any tips on how to prevent this from happening.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the computer you are sending the email from have a [reverse PTR record](http://aplawrence.com/Blog/B961.html)? Jeff has [a great post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html) up today detailing the necessity of having one.

Another option is to just use one of the cloud based email providers. Some suggestions:

- http://postmarkapp.com
- http://www.socketlabs.com

Also make sure that the IP address you are using for email hasn't been black listed: http://www.mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx.

Comment: Thanks for the info - will take a look into the links you provided

Comment: @Gublooo for the record what'd you end up doing?